# Does Apex have a remainder function that works with decimals?

Tags: apex

I was trying to use math.mod(decimal,decimal) but I get the following error:

`Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void mod(Decimal, Decimal) from the type System.Math`

I know it is easy to make my own but it seems odd.

**Update:**

Here is what I implemented to account for lack of support.

```
    public static Decimal decimalMod(Decimal x, Decimal y){

    Decimal remainder = 0;

    if(x != 0){
        Decimal firstResult = x / y; 
        Decimal flooredResult = math.floor(firstResult);
        Decimal flooredProduct = flooredResult * y;
        remainder = x - flooredProduct; 
    }

    return remainder;
}

// example: decimalMod(5.01, 0.25) would result in a remainder of .01.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Spring 19 (and all prior versions), we only have `mod(Integer, Integer)` and `mod(Long, Long)`. There is no known information of when, or if, we might get a built in for Decimal or Double values.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone happens upon this page, one way to do this is (assuming `someDecimal` is non-null):

```
Decimal remainder = someDecimal - someDecimal.round(RoundingMode.DOWN);
```